# What happens if one uses delete[] after a delete?

Tags: c++, memory-management, dynamic-programming, delete-operator

I am trying to implement a self-made vector class with dynamic length. The idea is to use a pointer and dynamically allocated space as follows.

```cpp
template<class T>
class myVector
{
    int size;
    T* array;
public:
    myVector(int n): size(n), array(new T[n]){}
    ~myVector(){delete[] array;}
    T pop();
    ...
}
```

and if I need to push, I create a new object with a new pointer pointing to newly allocated space and copy the whole whing. Now I am stuck on the pop part because I don't know how to free the unused space after pop() is called.

Is it okay if I use delete in pop() like this

```cpp
T pop()
{
    T = *(array+size-1);
    delete array+size-1;
    return T;
}
```

But if I do this then when the destructor is called the popped place gets deleted twice, and I think something could go wrong with that. And I know I can wait until the whole array is empty before deleting, but it might happen that a very large array is allocated at first and gets popped a lot while the program's running, which could lead to a large number of unused spaces if I don't free them in the middle.

**My questions:**

(1) What happens if I were to write delete in pop()?

(2) What can I do? (preferably with delele only)

Comment: (1) On my machine, it terminates the running application.  (2) Never use `new`/`delete` and never use `new[]`/`delete[]`.  Instead, use `std::vector`, `std::make_unique` or `std::make_shared`.

Answer (score 4):

Your code is severely flawed.

Firstly, any `new T[N]` must be deleted with a `delete[]`. So your destructor needs to use `delete[]`, not `delete`.

Then, you cannot use `delete` to pop single elements from your buffer. That is **undefined behavior** (security risk) because the elements have not been allocated with `new`.

The way a real vector handles this, is to allocate a buffer of `char` on the heap, and then manually invoke the constructors and destructors of `T` in the buffer, by using *placement `new`* and *explicit destructor calls*.

Answer (score 1):

You must `delete` what you `new` and `delete[]` what you `new[]` and nothing else. You cannot delete individual elements from a dynamically allocated array, only the whole thing. Your current destructor has Undefined Behavior because you `delete` something that you created with `new[]`.

1) Undefined Behavior happens. Don't do it.

2) Delete the whole array and allocate a new one with one less element. Since that's terrible for performance (adding `N` elements has `O(N^2)` runtime) you should look into the size + capacity thing that `std::vector` does.

Comment: Sorry about that, it should be delete[]. But my question is more about pop rather than the destructor. And if I want to free the unused spaces in the middle, what can I do in pop()?